# Cannot start hdfs service with CDH4: Datanode denied communication with namenode

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, cloudera

Ubunut 12.04 Server AMD64

any suggestion?

> Initialization failed for block pool Block pool BP-1276073141-127.0.1.1-1357815963565 (storage id DS-1319948814-127.0.1.1-50010-1357815971500) service to bpct-server-01/127.0.1.1:8020
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DisallowedDatanodeException): Datanode denied communication with namenode: DatanodeRegistration(127.0.0.1, storageID=DS-1319948814-127.0.1.1-50010-1357815971500, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-40;cid=cluster6;nsid=850502448;c=0)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager.registerDatanode(DatanodeManager.java:566)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.registerDatanode(FSNamesystem.java:3358)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.registerDatanode(NameNodeRpcServer.java:854)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.registerDatanode(DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:91)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.DatanodeProtocolProtos$DatanodeProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(DatanodeProtocolProtos.java:20018)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:898)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1693)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1689)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1687)

```
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1160)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:202)
at $Proxy10.registerDatanode(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
at $Proxy10.registerDatanode(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.registerDatanode(DatanodeProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:149)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.register(BPServiceActor.java:619)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:661)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well, associate hostname with wrong ip, stupid mistake

edit /etc/hosts solved the issue

Comment: It's good that you answered your own question. If this solved it for you, make sure you check it as accepted later. Not that you might not be able to do this right away, check back in a couple of days.